# filebeat service stops running

Tags: yaml, filebeat

The filebeat service on one of my Dev servers keeps stopping and crashing. This is the command I use to start the service:

```
sudo service filebeat start
```

[image: filebeat running]

Using `grep`, I can tell that with the stuff I'm getting back that the service is running. The picture indicates that the service is running.

After about 5 minutes, grep returns nothing and indicates that the service must has stopped:

[image: service stopped]

I do not have root access to look at the filebeat log so I can't tell what's going on for now through the log.

I do have a yaml file that has about 52 log paths. I'm thinking the yaml file may have a limit to how many paths it can hold and that may be why the service is crashing.

Comment: Are you not able to look at the filebeat log using sudo access ? I see you started filebeat using sudo with root privileges ?

Comment: @ben5556 nope, apparently i need root access request put in for approval first to be able to view the log file. i am in the process of doing that, but while i get back the request i was hoping someone may have some idea what may be behind this

Comment: Are you able to run `filebeat test config -c filebeat.yml` to check your filebeat config and see if it shows any errors ? Change your filebeat config file name if modified

Comment: @ben5556 i will have to check that tomorrow, unfortunately i dont have access from home now :/. but i will keep you posted tomorrow, will be available in the day?

Comment: Yes sure post it here

Comment: @ben5556 ok will do tomorrow!

Comment: @ben5556 check my answer, issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted with one of my colleagues, and since We have each application file in its own directory, when you have references to each one separately in the YAML file it crashes filebeat.

There is a limit apparently for those "harvesters"/paths per file (about 32). so when i reduced the "harvesters" that resolved the issue :)